# Is it posible to use Office SpellCheck API for POS tagging?

Tags: nlp, ms-office, spell-checking, pos-tagger

I am new in this filed and have no idea if NLP and POS tagging can found in Office SpellCheck API.

Since Office SpellCheck is some kind of language processing, is there possibility to use it as POS tagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please spend more time on reading about POS tagging and spell checking. Two are **VERY** different things. Answer to your question is **NO**